# RuntimeError: This event loop is already running aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

I want to create simple async web app

the app.py looks like this

```
async def get_favicon(link: str):
    return await _get_favicon(link)


async def handle(request):
   
    url: Optional[str] = request.query['url']
    result = await get_favicon(url)
    return web.json_response(result, status=200)


async def init():
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get("/", handle)
    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = init()
    web.run_app(application, port=8000)
```

Inside of get_favicon i have a _get_favicon function

```
async def _get_favicon(self, url: str, biggest: bool = True, **request_kwargs) -> Dict:

    request_kwargs.setdefault('headers', self.HEADERS)
    request_kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
    request_kwargs.setdefault('verify', False)

    response = await requests_async.get(url, **request_kwargs)
    response.raise_for_status()

    icons = set()

    default_icon = await default(response.url, **request_kwargs)
```

and default fucntion

```
    async def default(url: str, **request_kwargs: Dict) -> Optional[Icon]:
        parsed = urlparse(url)

        favicon_url = urlunparse((parsed.scheme, parsed.netloc, 'favicon.ico', '', '', ''))
         response = await requests_async.head(favicon_url, **request_kwargs)

         if response.status_code == 200:
            return Icon(response.url, 0, 0, 'ico')
```

When i try to run it, i got `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running` in `default` function at  `response = await requests_async.head(favicon_url, **request_kwargs)`. I don't understand when i got wrong. I don't create another loop. If i run `default_icon =  self.default(response.url, **request_kwargs)` without await i ll get coroutine object which is not exactly what i am looking for. I also tried to `default_icon = await asyncio.gather(default(response.url, **request_kwargs))` and got the same error.